# Ciclo for para crear una lista mediante indexación

Tags: python, loops

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
for i in range(len(elista)):
    print("Ingrese las notas para "+ str(elista[i]))
    for j in range(len(alista)):
        nota=int(input("Ingrese nota para alumno "+str(alista[j])+": "))
        notas[i][j].append(nota)
```

La última línea me tira error, no se como crear una lista con las notas diferenciadas por pruebas y por alumnos a la vez, me imagino solo dos indices.

¿Existe alguna manera mas sencilla de obtener esto, sin matrices?

```
elista=[P1,P2,P3]
alista=[A1,A2]

-Ingrese las notas para P1
Ingrese nota para alumno A1: 7
Ingrese nota para alumno A2: 4 

-Ingrese las notas para P2 
Ingrese nota para alumno A1: 5.5 
Ingrese nota para alumno A2: 3.7 

-Ingrese las notas para P3 
Ingrese nota para alumno A1: 3.8 
Ingrese nota para alumno A2: 3.2
```

Comment: Hoal Pride ¿Cual es el error?¿Inicializas la lista en algún momento?  No puedes usar un indice que no existe en la lista. Si tienes una lista vacía `lista = []` no puedes hacer `lista[0] = 2`.

Comment: Hola, y como puedo lograr ordenar las notas, segun alumno y numero de prueba, para luego volver a invocarlas.

La verdad no se como crearlo, esta parte me tira error: 

notas[i][j].append(nota)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder usar la indexación en una lista el elemento al que apunta el índice debe existir previamente. Es decir, si se tiene la lista `l = [7]` se puede hacer `l[0] = 4`, pero `l[1] = 4` lanzará una excepción (***IndexError***) ya que no existe el índice 1 en la lista.

Para que tu código funcione debes por tanto inicializar primero la lista:

```
notas = [[0 for _ in range(alista)] for _ in range(elista)]
```

Otra opción algo más legible es usar algo como los siguiente:

```
notas = []
for prueba in elista:
    print("Ingrese las notas para {}: ".format(prueba))
    notas.append([])
    for alumno in alista:
        nota = int(input("Ingrese nota para alumno {}: ".format(alumno)))
        notas[-1].append(nota)
```

Una alternativa que, aunque parezca más compleja en un principio, hace mucho más sencillas y eficientes operaciones de búsqueda o asignación posteriores es usar diccionarios:

```
notas = {}
for prueba in elista:
    print("Ingrese las notas para {}: ".format(prueba))
    notas[prueba] = dict.fromkeys(alista)
    for alumno in alista:
        nota = int(input("Ingrese nota para alumno {}: ".format(alumno)))
        notas[prueba][alumno] = nota
```

Luego podemos recuperar la nota de un alumno en una prueba usando las claves.

```
notas["Parcial 1"]["Pedro"]
```